# Installing Ubuntu on dual boot: prepare partitions window (step 4 of 7) is empty and grey?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, partitioning, installation, multi-boot

I want to install Ubuntu 9.10 on a PC which already has Windows 7 installed.

I have set up an unformatted primary partition with GParted and Ubuntu live:

[image]

During the installation I choose language (I'm Italian), time and keyboard, and then it shows me the "prepare partition" window, with no partitions at all and all greyed out!

[image]

Do you have any hints?

Comment: does it happens if you choose `English` language ?

Answer (score 0):

This is strange, as I assume you are using the same liveCD for both partitioning and installing, right? So I don't see how comes the system sees your HD on the first case and not in the second. Did you reboot the machine between partitioning and trying to install? If not I would first try that.

As a second option (this is not really a solution but a possible workaround) I would try the alternate install CD (available on the ubuntu website) which is text based.

Is there anything particular about your HD configuration? (Like virtual volumes or raid configurations?).

Answer (score 0):

yes, same liveCD for partitioning and installing, and i've rebooted many times to try that :(

No raid configuration, a one only SATA hard disk.

i've installed 9.04 and it works perfectly, i see all partitions in the partitions window :|

so this thing is a bug of Karmic (9.10).

then i've upgraded to 9.10, everything works now

Comment: OK so you're good to go - awesome... but questions remain.

This might be a problem with the 9.10 installer... or not.  You say it's a "primary" partition; there can only be 4 of those, right?

So I'm unsure - I looked at http://img266.imageshack.us/img266/618/gparted.jpg and it's not clear - what's the NAME of the partition you expected to be able to see in the installer?